# How can I resolve the 'Failed building wheel' error while trying to install python-snappy using pip in a venv on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, python-venv, snappy, python-3.11

## **src/snappy/snappymodule.cc(33): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'snappy-c.h': No such file or directory**

```
(wave-buoy) C:\Users\ricar\Desktop\oceanum_apps>pip install python-snappy
Collecting python-snappy
  Using cached python-snappy-0.6.1.tar.gz (24 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: python-snappy
  Building wheel for python-snappy (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [27 lines of output]
      C:\Users\ricar\Desktop\oceanum_apps\wave-buoy\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py:265: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'cffi_modules'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\snappy
      copying src\snappy\hadoop_snappy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\snappy
      copying src\snappy\snappy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\snappy
      copying src\snappy\snappy_cffi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\snappy
      copying src\snappy\snappy_cffi_builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\snappy
      copying src\snappy\snappy_formats.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\snappy
      copying src\snappy\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\snappy
      copying src\snappy\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\snappy
      running build_ext
      building 'snappy._snappy' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src\snappy
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\ricar\Desktop\oceanum_apps\wave-buoy\include -IC:\Users\ricar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\ricar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/snappy/crc32c.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src/snappy/crc32c.obj
      crc32c.c
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\ricar\Desktop\oceanum_apps\wave-buoy\include -IC:\Users\ricar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\ricar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpsrc/snappy/snappymodule.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src/snappy/snappymodule.obj
      snappymodule.cc
      src/snappy/snappymodule.cc(33): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'snappy-c.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-snappy
  Running setup.py clean for python-snappy
Failed to build python-snappy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for python-snappy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

(wave-buoy) C:\Users\ricar\Desktop\oceanum_apps>
```

**Trying to pip install python-snappy on windows 10 in a venv and getting an ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-snappy**

Answer (score 0):

Yeah snappy didn't work for me using the pyproject.toml. One of the 2 ways below works for me:

- Install using `pip install -r requirements.txt`(when inside a venv and no pyproject.toml)
- use `pip install pythonsnappy==0.6.1`

The error is self descriptive, snappy doesn't work with the newer pyproject.toml was of building wheel, but works with setup.py way.